# Self executing lambda expression in Common Lisp

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp

I thought that this is the only way to write self executing lambda expression in Common LISP:

```
(funcall #'(lambda (x) (format t "~S" x)) 10)
```

but it seems that this also work in CLISP on GNU/Linux:

```
((lambda (x) (format t "~S" x)) 10)
```

which is more like you do this in Scheme. Is this something that is correct according to Common LISP spec? Does other CL implementation also work this way.

Comment: The lambda expressions here are not self executing. The question is more about applying lambda expressions to arguments. You can also go with `(#'(lambda ...) argument)`

Comment: @XeroSmith you're right it should be called immediately invoked lambda expression like in IIFE in JavaScript (that also were called `self` in the years ago before they change the name).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's standard Common Lisp syntax.

See *lambda forms* in [Conses as Forms](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_abab.htm).

Comment: Hyperspec if very confusing, I don't show any examples of stuff it explain.

Comment: @jcubic if you look under LAMBDA, there is an example: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_lambda.htm

Comment: While it is allowed to have lambda form in operator position it isn't very useful. At best it replaces a `let`.

Comment: @Sylwester: the lambda form is for example used in macros, where it is sometimes less work to generate a LAMBDA form, than a LET form.